Clarification about a notation (or typo?) in ComplexityZoo for QAM class
In ComplexityZoo for QAM,
The last line goes as:

(QAM) Contains QMA and is contained in QIP(2) and $BP\&\#149;PP$ (and therefore PSPACE).

I need a help in deciphering "$BP\&\#149;PP$".
I suspect, it is (i) $QAM\subseteq BP.PP$.
Or, is it (ii) $QAM\subseteq BQP.NP$?
I suspect (ii) could also be a possibility, as in classical counterpart there exists Theorem: $AM=BP.NP$ (ref1, ref2).

The complexity class $\text{QAM}$ is defined by Marriott and Watrous in their paper "Quantum Arthur-Merlin Games" (arXiv)
From this paper:

$\text{QAM}$ is contained in $\text{BP}·\text{PP}$, the class obtained by applying the $\text{BP}$ operator to the class $\text{PP}$

